# How to Migrate Windows 8.1 Javascript Project to Windows 10

Tags: javascript, c#, html, visual-studio-2015, winrt-xaml

I'm using javascript and HTML to develop a Windows 8.1 Web base project (MFP 7.1). I'm 
also develop a Universal Windows c# application (UI is XAML file) and Windows 10 WindowsRunTime C# project. Windows 10 WindowsRunTime C# project is able to add a reference of Universal Windows c# application. But I'm facing a problem which is I need to add a reference from Windows 8.1 JS project to Windows 10 WindowsRunTime C# project.
[Error during add reference from Windows 8.1 project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSxPL.png)

I decide to ignore the error and add a reference to Windows 8.1 JS project. But I get an error during I build the project.
[Error during build project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URXbf.png)

Questions:-

1. Anyone have an idea to retarget/migrate Windows 8.1 JS project to Windows 10.0 project?
2. Anyone have an idea to launch/call C# project(with XAML) from Windows 8.1 javascript project?
3. Anyone have an idea to solve the add reference error and error during build project as state at above?

Thank you.

Comment: To migrate from windows 8.1 js to windows 10, you can just copy the code to the windows 10 project template and change some obsolete APIs. Why do you want to add JS project reference to c# windows 10 runtime component?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have a sample migrate Windows 8 js project to Windows 10? I need to call c# WinRT component function from my Windows js project. So I need to add reference for it.